# ASP.NET Core web app not get created in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0

I installed Visual Studio 2022 and created new ASP.NET Core web app project with .NET 8.0 framework, but after creating project, while viewing solution explorer there is no templates of ASP.NET application, I am confused

I installed .NET 8.0 and Visual Studio 2022, in Visual Studio I installed 3 workloads - ASP.NET & web development, Azure development, .NET desktop development.

1. I created new project in Visual Studio 2022 by choosing "ASP.NET Core web app (Razor pages)"
   [image: creating project]
2. I gave it a project name, location, [configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhL5g.png)
3. I chose .NET 8.0 framework and created the project
   [image]
4. This is the result, it says solution 0 projects

[image]

But the templates, `.sln` and `.csproj` are created in the specified folder, then I right click on solution [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2MIq.png) and try to add existing `.csproj` file

But the final result is this:

[image]

Comment: Try running `dotnet --list-sdks` from the console

Comment: perhaps try and modify current VS installation. for this, open "visual studio installer", click "modify" for the current VS installation, and make sure the features you want are enabled. also try launching VS as administrator (maybe it's lacking write perms?)

Comment: also open CMD and run this command `dotnet --info` to be sure .NET SDK is installed

Comment: I ran dotnet --info and it says .NET SDKs installed: no SDKs found, Environment Variables: not set, global.json file: not found, but I installed .NET 8.0 then why its showing no SDKs found, btw I'm new to development and I started with .NET. so clarify me this

Answer (score 0):

> I installed Visual Studio 2022 and created new ASP.NET Core web app
> project with .NET 8.0 framework, but after creating project, while
> viewing solution explorer there is no templates of ASP.NET
> application, I am confused

Well, based on your scenario and description, you should [first execute following command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows):

Check SDK and Runtime:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
dotnet --list-runtime
dotnet --info
```

Once you have executed above command, you should have following output:

[image]

**Note:** Keep in mind if we want to build .NET based project in visual studio or within your machine we  should have [SDK( software development kit )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net80). So from above command you should have [required files installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net80) accordingly.  If you don't have the `.NET SDK installed`, [download and install](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) the latest version from the [official Microsoft .NET website](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download)

Required file in Visual studio installer:

In addition, while you have installed visual studio make sure you have checked asp.net web development checked within your visual studio installer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Check csproj details:

Once you are done with SDK installation and version check up. Then restart our machine. Now you can create new asp.net core project within your visual studio and then, click on your project and check your csproj file. You should have following:

[image]

**Note:** Above steps should resolve your issue accordingly. In addition, please [refer to this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection)